# Adding library with resources to aosp package

Tags: android, android-layout, android-source

I am working with AOSP and I want to make my own library and use it in app (from packages/app/ ). My library has only one class:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
           Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_fragment, container, false);

    }

}
```

It has it's own layout. Android.mk for this lib looks something like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := my.own.package
LOCAL_NO_MANIFEST := true

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(call all-java-files-under, src)

LOCAL_RESOURCE_DIR := $(LOCAL_PATH)/res

include $(BUILD_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```

There are no compile errors. But when I use my lib in android application it crashes:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: my.own.package.R$layout
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at my.own.package.MyFragment.onCreateView(MyFragment.java:17)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1695)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:885)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1057)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1435)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1030):    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:474)
```

As I understand, android app can't find layout from my lib. So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score -1):

**(YOURPROJECT) right click** and then select **Properties->Java Build Path-> Select tab Order and Export** then your add lib will be in unchecked state. Check that lib the clean and run ur project.

Hope this help you.